# Handling of unforseen exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

If I want to write to a file and handle `IOExceptions` (in case the file is write-protected), I would do the following:

```
try
{
    var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.Default)
    {    
        sw.WriteLine(entry);
    }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    return ex.Message;
}
```

If I get an unexpected exception my program will crash, the user will report the bug and I will fix it. That is what I want.

So should I add another catch like:

```
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Will this make any difference and what is the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle unexpected exceptions, but a `catch` with a `throw` is redundant - the exception is thrown out of your method anyway. What you should do is ask yourself the question, "What can I do about this exception here?". For `IOException`, the answer is clear. You expect that exception could occur, can handle it, and can continue. In the case of a generic `Exception`, this may not be the place to handle it.

If you need to run some code when an exception occurs, add a `catch` for it. If your code cannot continue after that exception, throw the exception higher (by not handling it or using `throw`), and add handlers higher up in the call hierarchy. Maybe it can be handled at a higher level, and execution can continue. If not, your application will need to exit.

You can add a top-level `try`/`catch` block in your program's entry point, and catch unhandled exceptions there. Your application may even be able to continue after this (however, it's unlikely in any non-trivial application, given how high the exception will have been thrown at that point). To catch any other unhandled exception (those that are unhandled in threads, for example), you can add a handler to [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However, this is unrecoverable - your application will exit directly after. The `UnhandledException` handler is the last chance to do something with an exception before that happens, usually logging it to diagnose what went wrong.

Oh, also, if you're writing a WPF application, you can add a handler in your App.xaml for the [`DispatcherUnhandledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event on `Application`. That catches any unhandled exceptions that occur in the WPF dispatcher thread. Unlike the `AppDomain` handler above, unhandled exceptions on the dispatcher thread can be continued from - you can set `IsHandled` in the event args to `true` if it's OK for the application to continue.

Answer (score 1):

> So should I add another catch like

(almost) Never. At least not down in the stack trace. It will just make your application harder to read.

Most applications have entry point. For instance if you writing a windows service you typically create threads for the work. You can have a `catch (Exception)` in those to prevent them from crashing.

So what I'm saying is that you should in most cases only use catch all in the top layer to prevent your application from being harder to read or maintain.

**When everything fails**

Sometimes your application will crash anyway if you have forgot a catch all somewhere in the top layer.

You then want to use `AppDomain.UnhandledException` as it's invoked in for all application types in .NET. It will however not let you prevent the application from crahsing but just to log why your application is about to crash.

If you are coding UI applications based on winforms you can use the `Application.ThreadException` instead. However, it will only handle exceptions on the UI thread. Hence you still need to use the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` to log exceptions thrown on other threads.

All major library/framework in .NET have it's own way to allow you to handle unhandled exceptions. You need to look it up in the documentation of the library that you are using.

Comment: You could also use our service http://onetrueerror.com which takes care of all integrations for you.

Answer (score 0):

hi if you want to throw exception that the application will crash do this

```
 try
{
    var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.Default)
    {    
        sw.WriteLine(entry);
    }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

but in my opinion you should not let it crush but only show the error message

in the catch call function write to file and then return the message and show to user . hope it helps

```
 public static void WriteCustomLog(string msg)
            {
                FileStream fs = null;
                StreamWriter sw = null;
                FileStream fs1 = null;
                StreamWriter sw1 = null;
                try
                {
                    //check and make the directory if necessary; this is set to look in the application
                    //folder, you may wish to place the error log in another location depending upon the
                    //the user's role and write access to different areas of the file system
                    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\Log\\"))
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath + "\\Log\\");

                    string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy");

                    //check the file
                    fs = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\Log\\Log" + date + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                    sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                    sw.Close();
                    fs.Close();

                    //log it
                    fs1 = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\Log\\Log" + date + ".txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                    sw1 = new StreamWriter(fs1);
                    sw1.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Message: " + msg + Environment.NewLine);
                    sw1.Write("Date/Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                    sw1.Write("=======================================================" + Environment.NewLine);

                }
}
```

and then dispose the objects 
was not tested

Comment: I do not want the application to crash on a IOException as I except that can happend and therefore handel it. Its is about the exceptions I do not except. Should I catch them and throw or just dont do anything.

Comment: So return the message in the exception show it to the user and write a custom log with the error (return ex.Message;)

Comment: This resets the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Maybe you want to use the [Application.ThreadException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event too.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch(Exception)
{ 

    throw;    
}
```

does nothing. The exception is thrown with it's original stack trace and no additional actions are performed. You could catch general exceptions, which gives you the option to provide additional logging and/or present the user with a nicer error message

```
catch(Exception ex)
{ 
    LogError(ex);
    if (weDontCareThisWasntImportantAnyWay)
    {
        if (theUserShouldBeNotifiedAtThisPoint)
        {
            SomehowNotifyTheUser(ex);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Maybe something else cares
        throw;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could catch the exception and then inside check what type the expception is. Then decide how to handle it.

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  if(ex.InnerException is IOException )
  {
    // do  something
  }
 else
  {
   // do something else
  }
}
```

Comment: Why? You can just catch(IOException) and then have a fallback to Exception() by chaining the handlers.

Comment: @kha: Didn't you notice that he checked the INNER exception. You can't catch that.

Comment: @jgauffin The question was about catching IOException and other types of exception that may occur when calling a method and this answer was checking the inner exception of a catch all exception as a way to do it. This approach is faulty: not every exception has an InnerException and not every IOException is re-thrown (in fact I would be surprised if it was the standard behaviour to rethrow an IOException) which means this solution wouldn't handle an IOException that was the cause of the exception and not re-thrown as another type of exception with an InnerException of an IOException object.